# Wordpress page shrinks perfectly but website page does not

Tags: css, image

I'm trying to understand what coding difference there is between this [Wordpress page](https://melbournecriminallawyersblog.com/) and this [website page](http://www.criminal-lawyers.com.au/criminal-law/offences).

If I zoom out the pages, the Wordpress page shrinks perfectly along with the images and the spacing in between. But for the website page, it also shrinks but not as good as the Wordpress page. The images get compressed and the spacing is lost. I am worried how the website page might look if viewed in a monitor with a different resolution.

[image: size reduction]

Anybody have an idea why this is?

Comment: looks ok in Chrome browser. Put some more details in your question i.e browsers tested on etc

Comment: nope, I did try it on Chrome and the website page shrinks just like how it does via mozilla. if you look at the lower images, the spacing between images is lost after shrinking. whereas the wordpress page retained everything perfectly fine

Comment: just make pictures part parent width 100%

Answer (score 0):

I played with this in the inspector and this seems to make it behave right.

```
.one-fourth {
    width: 31%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px){

    .one-half, .one-third, .one-fourth {
        margin: 0 0 0 3.44%;
        width: 33%;
        float: left;
    }

}
```

And then remove all the clear fix divs in between .one-fourth divs.